# Why my ttfb is very high when my nodejs application is very fast?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have nodejs application that I serve html file:

```
const index = resolve('public/index.html');
const html = fs.existsSync(index) ? fs.readFileSync(index, 'utf-8') : '';
app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send(html);
  res.end();
  // res.sendFile(resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

My application is in aws: web -> ALB (aws) -> nginx -> nodejs.

My problem is the ttfb is too way long for every resource.

Look at `/` url: from cloudwatch (take about 1ms):

[image]

and from my devtools at the same time (take about 157ms):

[image]

This is how I know how much take to request to be processed:

```
  const startHrTime = process.hrtime();

  res.on('finish', () => {
    const elapsedHrTime = process.hrtime(startHrTime);
    const elapsedTimeInMs = elapsedHrTime[0] * 1000 + elapsedHrTime[1] / 1e6;
    console.log('%s : %fms', req.path, elapsedTimeInMs);
  });
```

So, why I get this high `ttfb` and what I can do about it?

Comment: did you try running Node in production mode? It's way faster

Comment: sure. it is in production mode

Comment: Also, you're reading a file (synchronously, on top of this). So, it takes time

Comment: no no sorry my mistake. I edit my question. I do not read the file every time

Comment: this is how it in my production server